# Win32 exe not finding resources compiled in a .lib

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a pretty plain Win32 application that links against a library I wrote that contains resources in an .rc file. The problem is that the .exe doesn't seem to find those resources. But if I move the .rc file from the library project to the .exe project resource loading works.

What step am I missing? I have the impression I have to call some kind of general resource setup/loading function because the resources aren't directly in the executable but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VC++ resources in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531502/vc-resources-in-a-static-library)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I couldn't find the magic combination of search keywords to find that article.

Answer (score 0):

May be something shifted, but early years it wasn't possible to store resources in .lib
But it is absolutely legal to place them to .dll
Just change type of your project.