# Use a .tga (targa) file from resource in OpenGL c++ project

Tags: c++, opengl, resources

I am trying to create a texture for my 3D models. It works fine as long that I just load the image file. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express, and I have been searching for a solution on this "problem", loading a .tga from resource into my project, and use it as an OpenGL texture.

```
//resource.h
#define TEST_TGA 201

//resource.rc
TEST_TGA TGA "test.tga"
```

I don't know if I actually can do this? But I really having a hard time finding any articles or topics about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [stb_image](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) library to load TGA images among other formats. You should be able to get the resource data with Windows API functions such as [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240388/160539) for example code on loading binary resources.