# Loading Win32 resource file as wstringstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, resources

This a follow up of the question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240188/how-to-load-a-custom-binary-resource-in-a-vc-static-library-as-part-of-a-dll). I want to use a text file as a resource and then load it as a `stringstream` so that I can parse it.

The following code shows what I currently have:

```
std::string filename("resource.txt");
HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), filename.c_str(), RT_RCDATA);
HGLOBAL res = LoadResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), hrsrc);
LPBYTE data = (LPBYTE)LockResource(res);
std::stringstream stream((LPSTR)data);
```

However, I am unsure of how to extend this to read a unicode text file using a `wstringstream`. The naive approach yields unreadable characters:

```
...
LPBYTE data = (LPBYTE)LockResource(res);
std::wstringstream wstream((LPWSTR)data);
```

Since `LPBYTE` is nothing more than a `CHAR*`, it is no surprise that this doesn't work, but naively converting the resource to a `WCHAR*` (`LPWSTR`) does not work either:

```
...
LPWSTR data = (LPWSTR)LockResource(res);
std::wstringstream wstream(data);
```

I am guessing this is because a `WCHAR` is 16-bit instead of 8-bit like a `CHAR`, but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the encoding of your resource file? If its ASCII or UTF8, then you need an explicit conversion (like `MultiByteToWideChar`) to read it as a sequence of unicode characters.

Comment: Both of your proposed solutions work, as long as `resource.txt` is in fact UTF-16 encoded. Since you come to the conclusion that *"neither one works"*, it would help if you explained what does not work (what's the expected result and actual result?).

Comment: My `resource.txt` file is encoded in UTF-8, so the snippets above give me a string of arbitrary characters. The result I am looking for is to get a `wstring` of the contents of the file and store that in a `wstringstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment supplies the key missing detail. The file that you compiled into a resource is encoded as `UTF-8`. So the obvious options are:

1. Using the code in your question, get a pointer to the resource, encoded as UTF-8, and pass that `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert to UTF-16. Which you can then put into a `wstring`.
2. Convert the file that you compile into a resource to UTF-16, before you compile the resource. Then the code in your question will work.