# Visual Studio - 2 projects in Solution - working directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, directory

I have one C++ solution in my Visual Studio 2013.
The solution contains 2 projects. One is a Game Engine project, the other is a Game project.

The default project which launches is Game (it is .exe), the project depends on Game Engine project(Which is only .lib the Game project uses).

**The problem is, the GameEngine project uses always the $(ProjectDir) or working directory of Game, which I do not want. Even if it says in properties it will use the path to GameEngine folder, it eventually wont.**

**I want the GameEngine project code to use working directory of GameEngine project file (When I load files or Images from it`s folders).**

Please can you help me with this issue?

Comment: What you are asking for just doesn't make any sense.  A .lib gets linked into the final executable, it does not have a "working directory".  If you want to share assets between different games that all link that .lib then just store them in a well-know %appdata% subdirectory.  Use a post-build event to copy the files there with xcopy /d

Answer (score 0):

That's not how project references work. The idea is to produce a complete working folder in the `$(Outdir)` of the default project - in your example `C:\folder\Game\bin\x64\release` or similar - which you can later package into an installer and distribute.

Presumably, you want your GameEngine project code to run in GameEngine's ProjectDir - in your example `C:\folder\GameEngine\bin\x64\release` or similar - because you want the code to access additional files in that directory. If that's the case, you should add those files to GameEngine.csproj with `Build Action = Content` and `Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer` (see screenshot below). Then they will be copied to Game's `$(Outdir)`, and your code will be able to access them.

[image: Visual Studio - Content Copy if newer]

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for reply. I use C++ project, and i`m not sure I have the same options as is in your screenshot above. The "items" or folders I want to include contain shaders or textures, and I do not have included in project, they are just in folders near my GameEngine.vcxproj

Comment: You're right, my answer applies to C# projects. The concept still applies - you should find out what makes your files (shaders etc) get included in the GameEngine project, so the Game project knows to copy them to its output directory.

Comment: Sorry I am googling and searching, I have no idea how to I make the picture lets say in "MyFolder/picture.png" be included, so code in project can refer to that even if the project is as library project in my solution.

Comment: I believe you can include your files as [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zabda143.aspx). There seem to be [tricks for putting resources in a static library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531502/vc-resources-in-a-static-library).